# Benefits of the "Continue" instruction

Tags: automation, twincat, codesys

While doing some development work, I yet again run into the `CONTINUE` command, which I never really understood why anybody should use it.

If we take the example from [Beckhoff's documentation](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2528318603.html&id=):

[image: Screenshot of example code from the documentation]

```pascal
FOR nCounter :=1 TO 5 BY 1 DO
    nInt1:=nInt1/2;
    IF nInt1=0 THEN
        CONTINUE; (* to provide a division by zero *)
    END_IF
    nVar1:=nVar1/nInt1; (* executed, if nInt1 is not 0 *)
END_FOR;
nRes:=nVar1;
```

Couldn't we achieve the same result by inverting the `IF` statement:

```pascal
FOR nCounter :=1 TO 5 BY 1 DO
    nInt1:=nInt1/2;
    IF nInt1 <> 0 THEN (* inverted *)
        nVar1:=nVar1/nInt1; (* executed, if nInt1 is not 0 *)
    END_IF
END_FOR;
nRes:=nVar1;
```

I have the impression that in all cases, it's possible to use an `IF` rather than `CONTINUE`.

I'd like to know if you have a counter-example, or cases where the `CONTINUE` command has a real advantage when programming a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always going to be a way to express the same logic without using `CONTINUE`.  In many cases it can be done with just an IF block, but in sometimes it is a bit more complicated, such as if the `CONTINUE` is used inside an `IF` block that is inside the `FOR` loop.

Ultimately, it is a matter of preference. I often use `CONTINUE` in cases where it avoids creating an indentation level for the code that follows. Some people may hate CONTINUE because "`GOTO` considered harmful" (`CONTINUE` is not the same as `GOTO`, it does not allow jumping to arbitrary code locations).

There probably are cases where `CONTINUE` saves some CPU cycles, but it is likely to be so negligible that there are no cases where that would be a practical concern or justification.

So, to sum it up, `CONTINUE` has an advantage when it yields code that is easier to understand, which is subjective, so it is up to you to decide.

Comment: I would add to this point, that CONTINUE generally allows the rest of the code inside the loop to not be nested inside if the IF statement, a bit like RETURN ing early from a function. Which IMO leads to easier to read code. As Fred says, it's subjective.

Comment: Agreed about the rest of the loop not having to be nested in an IF block, this is what I meant by "avoiding an indentation level". It is very common for the first thing you do in a loop is check if that iteration needs to do something or not (e.g. because of the state of an array element read using the index over which you loop), so there is often that occasion for a an "IF ? THEN CONTINUE ; END_IF" one-liner which, to me is cleaner.